\\ doesnt bring figure to the next line
Why doesn't the \\ bring the figures to the next line ? I mean these lines
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\\

in the MWE below. This is the figure I get. They are all in one line. 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\begin{document}

\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.2em}}
\def\imagevspace{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
\def\cropa{5cm}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagevspace

\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,trim={0 {\cropa} 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}\vspace{0.1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}   
    \footnotesize{True Left} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\[-0.3cm]
    \footnotesize{Pred Left} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
    \footnotesize{True Right} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
    \footnotesize{Pred Right} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] 
        \node[inner sep=0] (bar4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth,height=\barheight\textwidth,trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\\vspace{-0.3cm}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}

    % max t = 246
    
    % image1 t=0
    \def\time1{0}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image1.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);

    % image2 t=40
    \def\time1{0.16}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image2.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image3 t=70
    \def\time1{0.284}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image3.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image4 t=92
    \def\time1{0.365}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image4.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image5 t=120
    \def\time1{0.487}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image5.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image6 t=160
    \def\time1{0.650}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image6.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image7 t=190
    \def\time1{0.772}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image7.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
    % image8 t=220
    \def\time1{0.894}
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(image8.south)+(0,0)$)--($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$);
    \draw let \p1=(bar1.west), \p2=(bar1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [dotted, line width=0.5mm] ($(bar1.north west)+(\n1,0)$)--($(bar4.south west)+(\n1,0)$);
    
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{x}
\label{fig:qualitative-mocap}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}


I'm afraid that when I try to compile your code, I get the following error message at line 150: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Aside: I think you may want to change the 16 instances of \subfloat{ to \subfloat{%.

Of course, if you place everything in a single \makebox[\textwidth]{...}, there will be no line break. It's quite difficult to understand what you want to achieve with all those \subfloat commands that make no sense at all, if you don't specify subcaptions.
